# Entity Framework 4 "Generate Database from Model" to SQLEXPRESS mdf results in "Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database"

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 RTM. I want to do model-first, so I started a new MVC app and added a new blank edmx. Created a few entities. No problem. Then I "Generate Database from Model", and allow the dialog to create a new database for me, which it does successfully as 'mydatabase.mdf' in the app's App_Data directory.

Then I open the generated sql file (in Visual Studio). To run it of course I have to give it a connection. I am not sure if it's right, but I used '.\SQLEXPRESS' and Windows authentication. No idea how I'd tell it where the MDF is.

Then the problem -- upon executing it, I get:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not locate entry in sysdatabases
>   for database 'mydatabase'. No entry
>   found with that name. Make sure that
>   the name is entered correctly.

And indeed there were no tables created in the MDF.

So... what am I doing wrong, or am I off my rocker expecting this to work? :)

Comment: If it is generating a database for you in the app_data directory then why are you opening the generated sql file in VS? Why not double-click on the database in App_Data?

Comment: It only creates the MDF as empty. I have to run the generated SQL to create the tables, relationships, etc. The creation of the MDF isn't really done by EF I dont think -- its just part of the process of selecting a 'connection' and giving it a new db name rather than select and existing one.

Comment: I'm afraid I never did solve this...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.   I could not get an MDF file in my App_Data folder to work.   There really is only one reliable solution.  Install SQL Server 2005 or 2008 R2 developer edition and create your database in that server.  SQLEXPRESS just doesnt seem to work at all with the Entity Framework 4.0.  I have had no trouble with database generation with either SQL Server 2005 or 2008R2 Developer Edition.